# Typescript factory class results in missing properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, factory

I'm looking to create a factory class using Typescript--a class that returns the object of another class.

I have a class, extended by another class:

```
class Customer {
  static member = true;
  id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  static c_type = "Basic Customer";

  makeTransaction():string {
    var transaction_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    console.log(this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1]);
    return transaction_id;
  }

  constructor(public name:string, public dob:string) {}

}

class VIPCustomer extends Customer{
  vip_num = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  vip_discount:number;
  static c_type = "VIP Customer";

}
```

I've also created the factory class, intended to return the objects:

```
class CustomerCreator {
  static create(event: Customer, type:string) {
    if (type == 'Basic') {
      return new Customer(event.name, event.dob);
    }
    if (type == 'VIP') {
      return new VIPCustomer(event.name, event.dob);
    }

  }
}
```

I am able to create the object like so:

```
var customer_2 = new Customer('Matthew', '12/70');
```

However, when I try to use the creator:

```
const customer_1 = CustomerCreator.create({name:'Pii', dob:'03/19'}, 'Basic');
```

I get the following error :

```
Argument of type '{name: string, dob: string}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Customer'.
Property 'id' is missing in type '{name:string, dob:string}'
```

If I include all of the fields and methods in the constructor, it works. But, is there any way to work around doing that?

UPDATE:

I've moved the id definition into the constructor, as suggested, but it doesn't solve my issue.

```
class Customer {
  static member = true;
  id:string;
  static c_type = "Basic Customer";

  makeTransaction():string {
    var transaction_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    console.log(this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1]);
    return transaction_id;
  }

  constructor(public name:string, public dob:string) {
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling  `CustomerCreator.create()`?. While the @Umair abid answer has a valid point, the error you are receiving suggests that you're passing an object to `CustomerCreator.create()` which does not comply with the `Customer` type. I bet the `event` parameter should not be of type `Customer`.

Comment: @Sergeon If I remove all of the fields and methods, I am able to return a Customer object using just the structure of the constructor. I've updated my post to demonstrate how I call create().

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that you are trying to set the `id` while declaring. You need to set the `id` in constructor which will be set for each newly created object of `customer`

```
class Customer {
  static member = true;
  id = string;
  static c_type = "Basic Customer";

  makeTransaction():string {
    var transaction_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    console.log(this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1]);
    return transaction_id;
  }

  constructor(public name:string, public dob:string) {
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
  }

}
```

This seems like an interesting read https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

So your signature of `CustomerCreator.create` is:

```
static create(event: Customer, type:string): Customer;
```

As you wrote it, it takes a Customer (the `event`) and a string (the `type`), and it returns a `Customer`.

And you're invoking it with the following:

```
const customer_1 = CustomerCreator.create({name:'Pii', dob:'03/19'}, 'Basic');
```

This leads to the error:

> Argument of type '{name: string, dob: string}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Customer'.
>   Property 'id' is missing in type '{name:string, dob:string}'

Since you're providing the following object as the `event` parameter:

```
{name:'Pii', dob:'03/19'}
```

Which not complies to the `Customer` type, because it does not have an `id`, but the signature of the `create` method requires a `Customer` for the event parameter.

I think you should use another type in the `create` definition, for example:

```
type CustomerEvent {
  name: string;
  dob: string;
}

class CustomerCreator {
  static create(event: CustomerEvent, type:string) {
    if (type == 'Basic') {
      return new Customer(event.name, event.dob);
    }
    if (type == 'VIP') {
      return new VIPCustomer(event.name, event.dob);
    }

  }
}
```

This will fix the error.

### Update

`CustomerEvent` is just an example. You may as well define a type on the fly in the method definition:

```
static create(event: {id: string, name: string}, type:string) ...
```

The point is that your original problem was due to the object passed to `create` not complying with the `Customer` type.

The decision to create a new type `CustomerEvent` -or the likes-  strongly depends upon that kind of object will be passed along in a lot of parts of your application or not.

Comment: Would this be considered a good practice, or am I just going about this the wrong way? Also..."type CustomerEvent" is resulting in error "= expected". It only works if I create a class CustomerEvent, which seems like it may be hard to maintain in the long run.

Comment: I edited tbe answer with more info. What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I think what is confusing to me, is that the Customer constructor only requires these two parameters to create the object, yet I am unable to call create() using only these two parameters. The error message related to the type CustomerEvent is "'=' expected".